# User Picker is not returning thumbnail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker, google-workspace

I created a simple Ticket Kiosk using Google App Maker. Everything was working great but now the user thumbnails are not showing up. Essentially, it uses the User Picker widget with a Directory database that pulls everyone in our g suite domain. It's still pulling all of the user data but the URL that it is pulling from the **ThumbnailPhotoUrl** field no longer comes up with an image. The URL is still exactly the same as it was when it was working so I don't think it's the code, but maybe something changes in G Suite? Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks,

Dom

Comment: I've checked it 1 minute ago and it works well for me. Maybe it is a transient issue? Can you still reproduce it? Did you try to clear your browser's cache or another browser?

Comment: Thank you for confirming that it still works for you. I appreciate you checking for me. It is still not working for me.I have tried on different browsers and using different user accounts. I'm thinking something was changed in the G Suite settings. I'll have to poke around

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue between Google and our network. We were getting 404 errors when trying to pull up pictures from Hangouts as well. It resolved itself overnight.